# Searching for files using NSMetadataQuery does simply nothing

Tags: swift, xcode6

I try to use NSMetadataQuery and NSPredicate to search for files. After several hours of trying and searching for solutions (I'm new to swift) I have a small example. It compiles fine but the results are zero. I tried different predicates but at the end metadataQuery.resultCount is always 0.
Anyone has an idea whats going wrong?

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
var metadataQuery: NSMetadataQuery!
var metadataQueryDidUpdateObserver: AnyObject?
var metadataQueryDidFinishGatheringObserver: AnyObject?


@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "initalGatherComplete:", name: NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification, object: nil)

    metadataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
    metadataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryIndexedLocalComputerScope]
    metadataQuery.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K LIKE '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey)
    metadataQuery.startQuery()

}

func initalGatherComplete(notification: NSNotification) {
    metadataQuery.stopQuery()

    let resultCounter = metadataQuery.resultCount
    NSLog("%lu", resultCounter)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification, object: nil)
}
```

And last but not least: the current predicate should list all files, but at the end the predicate should only list applications. whats the best practice to create such a predicate? I planned to filter for the extension .app but perhaps there is a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like NSMetadataQuery is not working correctly with swift. I cannot find a working example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your [predicate syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001849-CJBEJBHH).  The `LIKE` operator isn't available for `NSMetadataQuery` predicate searches (in fact `NSPredicate` uses a quite similar but actually different set of operators and behavior in the context of Spotlight metadata searches.)

`NSMetadataQuery`'s syntax for glob searches just uses an equals sign:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K ==[cd] '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey)
```