# Can't get iCloud metadataQuery to work

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, swift2

I have an issue with the iCloud metadataQuery.

I am trying to fetch some documents from iCloud but when I call the NSPredicate function I get the following error in the console of Xcode:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the
>   dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type
>   information available.

*Note: I am using Swift version 2.*

This is my function:

```
var _iCloudQuery:NSMetadataQuery!
    func iCloudQuery()->NSMetadataQuery?{

        if (_iCloudQuery == nil) {
        _iCloudQuery = NSMetadataQuery.init()
        _iCloudQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]
        _iCloudQuery.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = '*')", NSMetadataItemURLKey)//
        // Set observer here
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "processCloudQueryResults:", name: NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification, object: _iCloudQuery)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "processCloudQueryResults:", name: NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification, object: _iCloudQuery)



        }

        return _iCloudQuery
    }
```

I already figured out that `processCloudQueryResults` never gets fired because there are no items in `icloudQuery` but still there are documents in my iCloud container so there should.

This is a related topic with no solutions:

[Searching for files using NSMetadataQuery does simply nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263182/searching-for-files-using-nsmetadataquery-does-simply-nothing)

Comment: Variables starting with underscores are a big no-no in Swift. Use computed properties if you want to do special stuff when getting a variable.

Comment: The underscore is added to just gif it a different name than the function. Not to mimic objective c.